# Google Chrome stopped working on Ubuntu 16.04 - it only shows orange box

Tags: google-chrome, orange-box

We have Ubuntu 16.04 with LTSP at work. Google Chrome worked until last week, but now it only shows orange box. I can blind type an URL and it is loaded but I can't see anything.
When I start google-chrome from command line I get these error messages:

```
[20549:20549:0211/102212.749273:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(161)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[20581:1:0211/102213.132253:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
```

I tried to start google-chrome without gpu:

```
google-chrome --disable-gpu
```

but it didn't help. The error message about GPU process disappeared but the other one remained and I still cannot see anything.

Comment: You should try Chromium which is the best browser on non windoze computers is free open source and faster than chrome also is exactly the same interface you will be right way familiar with it, give it a try. By using the command google-chrome --disable-gpu causes heavy screen tearing and slowing because it will depend mostly on cpu for rendering etc

Comment: Yeah, Chromium works. But it's stupid that all bookmarks, passwords etc. get lost.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGo3C18GBNk

Comment: What's interesting is that chromium issues error messages too: [28082:28082:0211/134510.377213:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(372)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[28112:7:0211/134510.503745:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(124)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
[28112:1:0211/134510.809322:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
But it works.

Comment: It seem Chromium works (despite the console messages) and sadly it doesn't shows the orange box and you can't blindly type url's (like chrome does), sorry i can't help you with that or even suggest you something BUT you should upgrade your distro.

Comment: Chromium is showing an orange box, too. I first noticed it today.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are quite strongly affected by the problem, we tried to get to the root of the problem.
It turned out that the problem only occurred when you are trying to open chrome and/or chromium over a ssh tunnel.
After a web search we found a bugreport debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=949440

For convenience i am writing the solution here again.

Download a the c file a user attached in message #10.

```
wget "https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=949440;filename=XlibNoSHM.c;msg=10" -O XlibNoSHM.c
```

Compile this into a shared object file.

```
apt install libX11-dev
gcc -shared -fPIC -o XlibNoSHM.so XlibNoSHM.c
```

Then you can start chromium / chrome with:

```
LD_PRELOAD='libdl.so ./XlibNoSHM.so' /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
LD_PRELOAD='libdl.so ./XlibNoSHM.so' /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

Hope that helps to solve the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. When I compiled the library and started google-chrome I got this: `--2020-02-19 14:20:31--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.23.238, 2a00:1450:4014:80d::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.23.238|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

Crash dump id: 
     0K7d218d8e71cd5b64 
                                                       1,31M=0s

Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Goggle Chrome over ssh (our thin clients are connected to the server via ssh). Yesterday, after an update I found that Google Chrome is working again. It could have been fixed in an earlier version already, since I didn't check the functionality every time, but the important thing is that this issue disappeared.

The version of Google Chrome is 83.0.4103.97.